# Go Gorilla RecoveryHandler compile error

Tags: go, gorilla

Trying to use [RecoverHandler](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/handlers#RecoveryHandler), compile from Intellij fails.

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
r.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    panic("Unexpected error!")
})

http.ListenAndServe(":1123", handlers.RecoveryHandler(r))
```

I get below errors. Above code is from gorilla documenation as-is used and I did run `go get github.com/gorilla/handlers`.

```
src/main.go:48: cannot use r (type *mux.Router) as type handlers.RecoveryOption in argument to handlers.RecoveryHandler
src/main.go:48: cannot use handlers.RecoveryHandler(r) (type func(http.Handler) http.Handler) as type *mux.Router in assignment
```

How do I use RecoveryHandler of Gorilla?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the documentation is incorrect. `handlers.RecoveryHandler` can not be used as a http handler middleware itself, it returns one. Looking at the signature

```
func RecoveryHandler(opts ...RecoveryOption) func(h http.Handler) http.Handler
```

we can see that it takes 0 or more `handlers.RecoveryOption`s and returns a `func(http.Handler) http.Handler`. That func that it returns is what we actually want to wrap around our router. We can write it as

```
recoveryHandler := handlers.RecoveryHandler()
http.ListenAndServe(":1123", recoveryHandler(r))
```

Or you could do it all in one line

```
http.ListenAndServe(":1123", handlers.RecoveryHandler()(r))
```